# Why is this overdefined? Can't I move right vertical line to the rright?

Tags: solidworks

Why is this overdefined? Can't I translate eveything yellow horizontally to the right?

[image]

Comment: There is a coincident constraint at the bottom. So, I don't think you could move the whole thing to the right as you said. I think the 20.75 is the one causing the problem (both this and the coincident constraint are related to the same lines.

Comment: At the very bottom right of the sketch window there’s a button you can click where solidworks will automatically remove one constraint at a time until it is able to solve, and presents you with the options it finds.

Comment: The coincident constraint here is also likely one of the reasons you can’t delete the object below - couldn’t see from the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coincident relation at the bottom of the line on the right will prevent you from moving it horizontally. It is overdefined because your `20.75` dimension is probably too short or too long to reach the corner that the right-hand yellow line is coincident too. Your line is also vertical, meaning that it cannot move only the upper point of the yellow line to satisfy the dimension.

Hope this helps!